# SSRS 2008 Conditional data driven sum

Tags: reporting-services

The matrix's odd rows contain strings, representing integer numbers. The even rows contain strings, representing dates in mm/dd/yyyy format. The order is not guaranteed, it could be the other way around if someone changed the category names.

The grand total row has to be added to this matrix, but the following expressions throw an #Error:

```
=Sum(Iif(IsDate(Fields!Data.Value), 0, CInt(Fields!Data.Value)))
=Sum(Iif(InStr(Fields!Data.Value, "/"), 0, CInt(Fields!Data.Value)))
```

Converting 0 and field value to some other numeric data types did not work too.

Interesting enough, the expressions partially work for the grand total column, i.e. they calculate the numbers' row total, but #Error on the dates rows.

Protecting the row grand total as follows did not help either:

```
=Iif(Fields!Results.Value = "# of items", CStr(Sum(CInt(Fields!Data.Value))), "")
```

What is the correct way to implement data driven conditional totals?
I could do this in plain SQL and dump into a tablix in a heartbeat but this has to be wrapped in SSRS and used with an **existing** matrix which must not be changed otherwise.

Comment: What about using `IsNumeric` instead? `=Sum(Iif(IsNumeric(Fields!Data.Value), CInt(Fields!Data.Value), 0))`

Comment: I like Sam's comment, but I would also suggest putting your condition outside the equation, I.E. IIF(IsNumeric(Fields!Data.Value), sum(CInt(Fields!Data.Value)), 0) Or something like that...

Comment: Same error as before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This expression, combining the tips from both answers with additional protection, works:

```
=Iif(
    IsNumeric(Fields!Data.Value),
    Sum(Val(Iif(InStr(Fields!Data.Value, "/"), "", Fields!Data.Value))),
    0
)
```

Answer (score 3):

The `#ERROR` you get on the date rows is due to the `CInt` conversion failing.

This is because `IIF` is a function, not a language construct so both the true and false parameters get evaluated *before* being passed to the function regardless of the value of the boolean condition parameter. This means that:

```
=Sum(Iif(IsDate(Fields!Data.Value), 0, CInt(Fields!Data.Value)))
```

will always attempt the conversion to integer regardless of the result of the `IsDate` function.

Try using `Val` instead of `CInt`. The problem with `CInt` is it errors when the string to be converted is an inappropriate form; `Val` doesn't have that problem - it simply grabs whatever numbers it can. So you can use the expression:

```
=Sum(Iif(IsDate(Fields!Data.Value), 0, Val(Fields!Data.Value)))
```

and then simply format it like an integer.

Note that the `Val` function is still being run even when the field is not numeric but this expression succeeds because the `Val` function doesn't raise errors like `Cint`. We simply make the calculation and discard the result when the field is a date.

Comment: Is there more to your formula? Maybe the error is something else.

Comment: What do you mean, I am not following. You understand what the problem with Val would be? Val extracts the first number from a string it comes across, so the expression would sum all numbers and all numbers it would extract from the dates and give me a totally irrelevant result.

Comment: True, but the `IIF` discards the `Val` result and uses zero instead when the field value is a date, so it will sum all the numbers properly. The formula as shown above should work.

Comment: As my original issue is sovled, I don't have time to investigate, but all I can say is that `=Sum(Iif(IsDate(Fields!Data.Value), 0, Val(Fields!Data.Value)))` produced wrong results.