# DateDiff if SSRS unless NULL

Tags: sql, reporting-services, null, reporting

So, I am trying to get a DateDiff to work, but only if one of the items is not null.  I have

```
=DateDiff("d",Today,Fields!Seller_Approval_Date.Value)
```

but if Seller_approval_date is null, I want it to display a N/A.

I want it to display kind of the following, but I want it to display a difference in today's day and the displayed date:

[image: Display error]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to do this in reporting services then you can use

```
=Iif(IsNothing(Fields!Seller_Approval_Date.Value),"N/A"
,DateDiff("d",Today,Fields!Seller_Approval_Date.Value))
```

or if that doesn't work you could try a comparison against the length of the value.

```
=Iif(Len(Trim(Fields!Seller_Approval_Date.Value)) = 0
,DateDiff("d",Today,Fields!Seller_Approval_Date.Value),"N/A")
```

---

Final working expression

```
=Iif( IsDate(Fields!Seller_Approval_Date.Value), 
DateDiff("d",Today,Fields!Seller_Approval_Date.Value), "N/A" )
```

Comment: This pulls a N/A regardless of if the Seller_approval_date field displays anything.

Comment: That doesn't make sense, it should return back your datediff if `Fields!Seller_Approval_Date.Value` is not null.. Try changing the `IsNothing` to `IsDate`

Comment: I added a screenshot of what displayed with the IsNothing in there, and with the IsDate, it displays [this](http://screencast.com/t/RvnU0Y2VgD0v)

Comment: Sorry. I wasn't not believing you. I'm sure there's a reason why it doesn't work... two ticks and I'll add a different answer.

Comment: The new answer is actually still displaying the same issue as the last screenshot in our comment thread.

Comment: Usually Iif arguments require double protection in SSRS. I.e. you will need to check the 1st argument and then protect the 2nd argument with another Iif. See for example http://stackoverflow.com/a/20051113/2721750 I currently don't have an opportunity to quickly build a test case, but if you still have issues, reply and I'll find the time.

Comment: @CJBoat if you add `=Len(Trim(Fields!Seller_Approval_Date.Value))` to your table do the null / empty dates show 0?

Comment: @Sam add the Len to which part of it?

Comment: This expression works fine for my date column. Maybe it is something wrong with the textbox format?

Comment: Sam and @ajeh thank you, This works (an amalgam of the two)=Iif(
    IsDate(Fields!Seller_Approval_Date.Value),
    DateDiff("d",Today,Fields!Seller_Approval_Date.Value),
    "N/A"
)

Comment: @CJBoat I added this to the answer.. Glad I could help.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
=ISNULL(DateDiff("d",Today,Fields!Seller_Approvale_Date.Value), 'N'A')
```

Comment: ISNULL is not a SSRS function, and IsNothing doesn't work with this.